# how to find xpath form web page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xpath

I am trying to find xpath form web page. I used 3 add-ons to find xpath from web page
1) Xpather
2) FireFinder
3) Xpath checker
These returns some xpath. I copied those xpaths. In my application I am using nokogiri gem for screen scraping. If I psate those xpaths in my trial. That's not responding.

I tried the following procedure also. If I inspect the element that will open in html tab of firefug. After that I right click that element and copied the xpath. This xpath also not responding.

Partially related to this issue already i asked  question in stackoverflow. Phrogz answered my question. From his answer I red Xpath (w3schools) then I understood how to write xpath. But I can't expect user also write the xpath. If any add-on or any other tool available to get xpath from webpage is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using firebug for that.

But using nokogiri and mechanize I've never been a friend of XPath as a selector. I'm using CSS path instead. But the easiest and mostly secure way is using the id attribute if given.

Comment: Thanks for your riply. Also I tried with css path. If i m having same class in more than one place that css path returning all values( where those classes are used) but i need what i am expecting. So that's why i m trying with xpath.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using chrome..you can right click and do Inspect Element...and then search for the element u need in the webpage and right click for copy Xpath..

Answer (score 0):

You can Use **Google Chrome - Developers Tool**

1. **Right Click on the web element for which you want to get the x-path**
   [image: Select Element]
2. **Then Developer Tool window will get opened with Highlighted blue color entry then right click on that blue line and perform the action as shown in the image**

   [image: Copy xpath]